# How to tell the difference between animals based on attribute questions

Tags: python, attributes, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a program, an A.I. in fact, which learns the difference between animals and does so through a series of questions, these will determine which attributes the animal in mind possess. So what I want is a way to store animals with a selection of attribute questions, for example:

```
dog : does it have a wet nose?
      does it have whiskers?
```

All of these questions which answer 'yes' are attributes the dog has...any ideas? Also bare in mind that some animals have the same attributes, for example:

```
dog : does it have a wet nose?
      does it have whiskers?
cat : does it purr?
      does it have whiskers?
```

So I want the program to be able to ask multiple questions and determine which animal is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest thing you can do is to use a dictionary , which will keep up a relation between an attribute and list of animals that have that attribute for example :

```
attributes=[bite,scratch,purr,whiskers,...]
dic={
whiskers:[cat,dog]
purr:[cat]
scratch:[cat]
bite:[cat,dog,rat]}
dose it scratch
```

based on your question format for example:

```
   for each question:
     for each word in question :
       if word in attributes:
         attributesFound.append(word)
   animal=set(dic[attributesFound[0]])
   for each attribute in attributesFound:
   animal=animal.intersection(dict[attribute ])
```

say that we have this case

```
      does it purr?
      does it have whiskers?
```

the attributesFound would be [purr,whiskers] , animal would be [cat,dog]  then we enter the for each attribute loop

```
 for each attribute in [cat,dog] :
   animal=set(animal.intersection(dict[attribute ]))//in the first iteration animal would still be [cat,dog].
```

// however in the second iteration set([cat,dog]intersection([cat])) would leave you a set with only one element which will be cat

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) to do this task, you can use it to classify the animals based on his attributes, also might be usefull to take a look at  [Classification And Regression Tree (CART)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning), it will help you to decide what are the best attributes to do the classification.